# Turkish text-to-speech is not supported Galaxy Tab T-203

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am using text to speech in my apps using code below. Turkish doesn't work in Galaxy Tab T-203. Why doesn't my tablet support local language for text to speech? It is ok when I use it in phone.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
result = tts.setLanguage(locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing device language input as Gooogle Text To Speech